# Xamarin.Forms IOS communication serial/usb over cable with iphone?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, serial-port, usb

i am searching for a xamarin.ios .net library that offers the possibility to communicate with an usb connected device via ihpone. In android there are many libraries, but i cannot found a possibility for an iPhone serial port connection via xamarin.

Does someone has experiences in this case?
Thanks for possible helping

Edit: Is the linked Bluetooth library also a solution for usb communication?

Comment: the solution is a Bluetooth communication lib?

Comment: ExternalAccessory is the iOS API for any external device

Comment: thanks, but i have to join the mfi program for use this?